# ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding, Python - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm starting my adventure with Tensorflow. I think I installed everything correctly, but when running this code, PyCharm returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tymot/Desktop/myenv3/env/Tensorflow/all_good.py", line 15, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import (
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 19, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 54, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 158, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Failed to import any qt binding")
ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding
```

My code which I am trying to run:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_features = 2
num_iter = 10000
display_step = int(num_iter / 10)
learning_rate = 0.01

num_input = 2          # units in the input layer 28x28 images
num_hidden1 = 2        # units in the first hidden layer
num_output = 1         # units in the output, only one output 0 or 1

#%% mlp function

def multi_layer_perceptron_xor(x, weights, biases):

    hidden_layer1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['w_h1']), biases['b_h1'])
    hidden_layer1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(hidden_layer1)

    out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer1, weights['w_out']), biases['b_out'])

    return out_layer

#%%
x = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], np.float32)  # 4x2, input
y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0], np.float32)                      # 4, correct output, AND operation
y = np.reshape(y, [4,1])                                    # convert to 4x1

# trainum_inputg data and labels
X = tf.placeholder('float', [None, num_input])     # training data
Y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, num_output])    # labels

# weights and biases
weights = {
    'w_h1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, num_hidden1])), # w1, from input layer to hidden layer 1
    'w_out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden1, num_output])) # w2, from hidden layer 1 to output layer
}
biases = {
    'b_h1' : tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_hidden1])),
    'b_out': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_output]))
}

model = multi_layer_perceptron_xor(X, weights, biases)

'''
- cost function and optimization
- sigmoid cross entropy -- single output
- softmax cross entropy -- multiple output, normalized
'''
loss_func = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss_func)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for k in range(num_iter):
    tmp_cost, _ = sess.run([loss_func, optimizer], feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
    if k % display_step == 0:
        #print('output: ', sess.run(model, feed_dict={X:x}))
        print('loss= ' + "{:.5f}".format(tmp_cost))

# separates the input space
W = np.squeeze(sess.run(weights['w_h1']))   # 2x2
b = np.squeeze(sess.run(biases['b_h1']))    # 2,

sess.close()

#%%
# Now plot the fitted line. We need only two points to plot the line
plot_x = np.array([np.min(x[:, 0] - 0.2), np.max(x[:, 1]+0.2)])
plot_y =  -1 / W[1, 0] * (W[0, 0] * plot_x + b[0])
plot_y = np.reshape(plot_y, [2, -1])
plot_y = np.squeeze(plot_y)

plot_y2 = -1 / W[1, 1] * (W[0, 1] * plot_x + b[1])
plot_y2 = np.reshape(plot_y2, [2, -1])
plot_y2 = np.squeeze(plot_y2)

plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=y, s=100, cmap='viridis')
plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y, color='k', linewidth=2)    # line 1
plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y2, color='k', linewidth=2)   # line 2
plt.xlim([-0.2, 1.2]); plt.ylim([-0.2, 1.25]);
#plt.text(0.425, 1.05, 'XOR', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks([0.0, 0.5, 1.0]); plt.yticks([0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
plt.show()

#%%
```

I think it follows another version of python. How can I run the code without error. 
I installed qt-binding and added tensorflow to my PyCharm.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's an [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11929) on the matplotlib Github site that addresses your error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It solved my problem.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 103):

make sure you have `PyQt5` installed. you may open a python shell and try:

```
import PyQt5
```

if it fails then you can install it via:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

If you are on macOS or Linux be careful that you might need to run

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

Comment: `Collecting PyQt5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/fb/eb51731f2dc7c22d8e1a63ba88fb702727b324c6352183a32f27f73b8116/PyQt5-5.14.1.tar.gz (3.2MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.2MB 843kB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   `

Comment: I am unable to use matplotlib inside conda environment. python exits as soon as i hit the statement plt.show(), where as it works perfectly when i install python directly

Answer (score 0):

I met the same `ImportError` when using `%matplotlib qt`.
Following Foad's answer solved my problem.

I use Archlinux so I tried

```sh
sudo pacman -S python-pyqt5
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is also useful:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github

> **If the file was added with your most recent commit:**
>
> ```
> $ git rm --cached giant_file
> # Stage our giant file for removal, but leave it on disk
> $ git commit --amend -CHEAD
> # Amend the previous commit with your change
> # Simply making a new commit won't work, as you need
> # to remove the file from the unpushed history as well
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with .so libraries which only revealed with

```
import PyQt5.QtCore
```

(libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.15' not found...). The solution I have found is to install PyQt 5.14.x (`pip install 'PyQt5<5.15'`)

Answer (score 0):

If you come from `pyCx` - this is solved here: https://github.com/hsayama/PyCX and here: https://xin-wang-kr.github.io/posts/2023/03-PyCX

Basically you need to:

1. `!pip install PyQT6`
2. add those lines in the `pycxsimulator.py` file inside PyCX directory

```
import PyQt6.QtCore
import os
os.environ["QT_API"] = "pyqt5"
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have qt installed. This fixed it for me.

```
 conda install -c anaconda qt
```

Answer (score -1):

I had that error on windows-VScode after the following magic command:

```
%matplotlib qt
```

Solved this error by completing the following steps:

- Uninstall Anaconda
- Reinstall Anaconda
- Restart, open Anaconda, start VScode from there.