# ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding

Tags: python, matplotlib, module, pip, pyqt5

I am getting this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 15, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py", line 12, in <module>
```

ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding

I have installed PyQT5 suing sudo pip3 install PyQt5,but still getting this error.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Please Help.

Comment: execute:  `python3.7 -m pip install pyqt5`

Comment: I believe this question has already been asked before. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346254/importerror-failed-to-import-any-qt-binding-python-tensorflow)